# UIGestureRecognizes - using on multiple layers

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

I am making an application that contains few layers on the image. This effect layers are children of UIView - EffectsLayerView. Effect1View, Effect2View and Effect3View are inside and few of them has UITextView. Those text views has UIPanGestureRecognize - I want to move them around the screen.

The structure looks like that

```
<EffectsLayerView>
  <Effect1View>
    <UITextView>
  <Effect2View>
  <Effect3View>
    <UITextView>
```

Unfortunately only that last one (Effect3View) receive touch and move the textView. UIGestureRecognizers are added to those text views. How it should be done to make it working? Every EffectView and EffectsLayerView has their classes.

I will be glad for help.

Answer (score 0):

**There are 2 requiremets:**

**1) For every view: self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true**

**2) Every view mush have an unique instance of UIGestureRecognizer**